# Is AccesControlException only raised in Applet when trying to access parent directory of the codebase directory?

Tags: java, applet, accesscontrolexception

This is the directory structure of an applet project I've created.

```
Project
|____classes
|____src
|____resources
```

- The applet is in the `src` directory.
- The classes are stored in the `classes` directory.
- All the images, sounds and other stuff are stored in the `resources` directory.

My problem is that when I try to load an image stored in the `resources` directory into my applet (which is in the classes directory when compiled), the JVM raises an `AccessControlException`. I read a lot of posts in stackoverflow about this, and now I understand why it is like this (to protect the user from accessing his files). I also read that you can write policy files to fix it or signed jars.

This is how I load my image:

```
Image image = getImage(getCodeBase(),"path/to/the/image/image.png");
```

I noticed that `AccesControlException` is not raised when the image I want to load is in one of the `classes` sub-directory. So I can't use `..` to access the  `classes` parent directory, and then the `resources` directory. Is there any way I can load my images without having to put them in a `classes` subdirectory and without using policy files or signed jars?

Answer (score 1):

> "I can't use `..` to access the classes parent directory, and then the resources directory.

Why not? Always worked for me.  See for example [this applet](http://pscode.org/fmt/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpscode.org%2Ftest%2Fmemapplet%2FMemoryTestApplet.java&col=2&fnt=2&tab=2&ln=0).  Unfortunately it is trusted (to allow it to reach cross-site), but if you are running an Oracle JRE, you should be able to <kbd>Cancel</kbd> the trust request to see something like..

[image: Accessing an URL from same site]

In this applet:

- HTML is at http://pscode.org/fmt/ (-> index.html)
- Code & code base is in http://pscode.org/lib/
- Source (resource) is in http://pscode.org/test/memapplet/MemoryTestApplet.java

The bottom line is, an applet should be able to get resources from *anywhere* on the home server for which the server will provide resources.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Everytime I try to access a "classes" parent directory, oracle jvm throws an AccessControlException. Perhaps it as something to do with the fact that I don't run my applet in a browser. Instead, I use the appletviewer command-line in msdos.

Comment: Aha!  That **is** the problem.  The applet viewer used to have no sand-box, but now it does, it is even tighter than on a web site for a fairly simple reason.  The `SecurityManager` cannot tell from a file system where the 'root' of the site is - so it takes a precautionary measure of only allowing sub-directories to be considered 'home site'.  At least, that is the best I could figure from working with it.  It is time to test in a browser, off a local server.

Comment: You're rigth. I tested my applet in a browser and I can access "classes" parent directory. Thank you for your help!